# How can I build a list of async tasks with argument for AsyncHTMLSession().run?

Tags: async-await, python-requests-html

From the documentation I have this example I've tested and works..

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

async def get_pythonorg():
    r = await asession.get('https://python.org/')

async def get_reddit():
    r = await asession.get('https://reddit.com/')

async def get_google():
    r = await asession.get('https://google.com/')

result = asession.run(get_pythonorg, get_reddit, get_google)
```

But what if my urls are variable?  I'd like to do this..

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

urls = ('https://python.org/', 'https://reddit.com/', 'https://google.com/')

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

async def get_url(url):
    r = await asession.get(url)

tasks = []
for url in urls:
    tasks.append(get_url(url=url))

result = asession.run(*tasks)
```

but I get..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    result = asession.run(*tasks)   File "/home/deanresin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 772, in run
    asyncio.ensure_future(coro()) for coro in coros   File "/home/deanresin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 772, in <listcomp>
    asyncio.ensure_future(coro()) for coro in coros TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_url' was never awaited
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TLTR:

It is because you are passing coroutines objects and not coroutines functions.

You can do:

```py
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

urls = ('https://python.org/', 'https://reddit.com/', 'https://google.com/')

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

async def get_url(url):
    r = await asession.get(url)
    # if you want async javascript rendered page:
    await r.html.arender() 
    return r

all_responses = asession.run(*[lambda url=url: get_url(url) for url in urls])
```

### Explanations:

The error is coming from `result = asession.run(*tasks)` so let's see the [source code](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/blob/master/requests_html.py) of `AsyncHTMLSession.run()` :

```py
def run(self, *coros):
    """ Pass in all the coroutines you want to run, it will wrap each one
        in a task, run it and wait for the result. Return a list with all
        results, this is returned in the same order coros are passed in. """
    tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(coro()) for coro in coros
    ]
    done, _ = self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    return [t.result() for t in done]
```

So in the following list comprehension you are normally passing a callable [coroutine function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine) and not [coroutine object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine)

```py
tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(coro()) for coro in coros
    ]
```

But you then in your error you have `for coro in coros TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable`.
So you are passing a list of coroutines objects and not coroutines functions.

Indeed when you are doing this:

```py
tasks = []
for url in urls:
    tasks.append(get_url(url=url))
```

You are making a list of coroutines objects by calling your coroutine function.

So in order to make a list of coroutines functions you can use lambda function like this:

```py
[lambda url=url: get_url(url) for url in urls]
```

Note the `url=url` in order to make the url parameter accessed when the lambda is defined.
More informations about this [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result).

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. Please provide some explanation as well, not just code.